# Where should my .txt file location be?

Tags: java, io

I'm designing a simple program for a server to keep track of a number. Several people will be accessing this server and pressing a button to increase the number by 1. Where should my saveFile.txt used to keep track of the number be located? Within the project resources? As a separate file on the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on your server organization and on the OS. But anyway the project resources is definitely a bad choice, because the resources can end into a war or jar file and be non modifiable at run time.

A common way would be to store the path of the file in a project resource. That way it will be easy to change it at config time, and you will be able to choose an external folder with appropriate permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Save it where the program is stored

Comment: Are you sure? It is common to store *executables* or other binary non modifiable files into read only folders. Just think of `/bin`, `/usr/bin` and `/usr/local/bin` or `/lib` and consorts for Linux or `Program Files` on Windows...

Comment: If I need to do this, I will store it on a server(AWS S3 or DB) but this is just a simple program